# implementing custom logic after login in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am trying to get some certain action done once the user is successfully logged in and i am wondering where could be the right place to get this done.

Should i create or edit user plugin  and write the logic in onLoginUser() function? If so, where do i import the plugin and fire the appropriate event.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place is, of course, to write the logic into the plugin.  That way you're insulated from any code changes that Joomla or VM upgrades would overwrite, as well as giving you full control over what's happening.

I'm pretty sure that Joomla installs an example.php and xml file in the plugins\user folder, which you can clone and modify.  Just be sure to have an entry in the joomla plugins table, so that Joomla knows it exists, and allows you to configure through the administrator pages.

Comment: Thanks Greg, i have already taken a good look at the example. At what point should i import the plugin and fire the event? Thanks

Comment: By putting an entry into the database, it's registered with Joomla, then you use the admin plugin manager to activate/configure it.  From there, the events all fire at the appropriate time automatically.  By the sounds of it, the right function to put your code in is onLoginUser